# NiFi - New attribute to create a new one with a previous attribute + harcoded text

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I'm trying to add a new "attributeX" to create an URL (using UpdateAttribute). This URL will be like this:
Part 1: harcoded value (eg.: "www.google.com/")
Part 2: evaluate attribute 1; if empty, use attribute 2: if not, use attribute 1.
Part 3: harcoded value (eg.: "/tests/")
Part 4: attribute3

Attributes 1,2 and 3 are present in the flow file from previous processors.
So, my goal is to get an url like this:
www.google.com/attribute1 OR attribute2/tests/attribute3

BUT; this "attributeX" needs a condition: if attribute3 is empty, I need to set the value as "empty": if NOT empty, I need to create that URL.

I was trying with regex expression but I couldn't get this done. My "isEmpty" and "ifElse" evaluations fails when I'm trying to set the the "ifElse" with harcoded values+attributes.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT: I didn't specify any of my tests because I did a lot of attempts and couldn't get the expected attribute.
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
${attributeA:isEmpty():ifElse(${literal("")},hardcodedText+${attributeB}+${attributeA})}
```

The expression works fine until the argument after the comma; if I use only 1 attribute/variable it works fine; but if I try with more than 1 attribute it's not recognized as as valid expression.

Comment: Welcome to SO!Please do mention what you tried and what didn't worked for you. Please read [how-to-ask a good question on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NahuelGonzalez You should share your expression language progress so we can see what you are doing.   It should be possible to do all the if/else logic in a single NiFi Expression Language string.  Sometimes the issue could be a simple (, :, or ' missing or misplaced.

However, I would maybe do this a different way.   Create your different combined attributes upstream from the isEmpty logic.  Then you can use the specific urls you need in the function response.

You can also use a RouteOnAttribute to split flow into to different updateAttributes that create different urls.   Then bring the flow back together for all the urls.

Comment: Steven, thanks for your reply. I have added an edit with my expression.
I'm trying to avoid using other processors because I have multiple pair of attributes (in the same flow file) where I have to apply this logic.

Comment: Thanks,  I played around with it and I am pretty sure you need to create your combined attributes before hand, then use them in the expression language when you need them.  Check out my template working on this here:  https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates/blob/master/Working_with_Expression_Languages.xml

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of the component attributes are defined prior to this expression (i.e. populated in an earlier component, or *empty* is ok), you can use an expression like this:

`${attributeA:isEmpty():ifElse(${literal("")},${literal("hardcodedText"):append(${attributeB}):append(${attributeA})})}`

The problems with the statement you tried (offered for learning, not criticism of what you tried):

- `attributeA:isEmpty():ifElse(${literal(""),...}` has a secondary clause which uses raw string concatenation, which is not supported by Apache NiFi Expression Language. You need to use the `append()` function here, or string interpolation outside of a clause (i.e. if `attributeA = x` and `attributeB = y`,  `${attributeA}_${attributeB}` -> `x_y`).
- When multiple "clauses" are combined, each needs the expression language syntax of `${}` to denote the clause so it can be interpreted. Otherwise it can be registered as a "token" which is unknown. So in the above case, you have multiple levels of EL clauses (in pseudocode for succinctness):

```
if (attributeA is empty) { (1)
    use "" (2)
} else {
    use "hardcodedText" + attributeB + attributeA (3)
}
```

Expression 3 is where additional EL clauses are necessary.

If the elements you were combining were all attributes, you could use the `${allAttributes(attributeA, attributeB, ...):join("")}` construction as well.